# how to get valid URL in combination of text and field content in VIEWS

Tags: views

Field HOSTNAME returns IP Adress.
I have to overwrite the field output .
Is there a way to modify this with an given URL like this:
'www.ip-tracker.org/locator/ip-lookup.php?ip=' and adding the field content of HOSTNAME to get an valid URL?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the `Rewrite results` option on your Field settings. Use the **Output this field as a link** option and enter only the URL with the field token replacement pattern at the end of it.

You can look up the token under `Replacement patterns` under the `Rewrite results` option.

If you need some more control over the link HTML you can use the `Rewrite the output of this field` where you construct the entire link HTML `<a href="...`.